# Weird Python / numpy UnboundLocalError behaviour

Tags: python, numpy

I am working on Python 2.7.12 and numpy 1.12.0 and observing the following behavior. Is this expected? I assumed that "**a**" to be in the scope w.r.t "**f2**" in both the cases how is accessing the "**a**" different than accessing **a[ind, :]**?

```
import numpy as np
def f1():
   a = np.zeros((1, 10))
   def f2():
      print locals()
      v = [0] * 10
      v[3] = 1
      a += v
   f2()


def f11():
   a = np.zeros((1, 10))
   def f2():
      print locals()
      v = [0] * 10
      v[3] = 1
      a[0,:] = v
   f2()
```

Result::

```
>>> f11()
{'a': array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])}
>>> f1()
{}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in f1
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in f2
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
>>>
```

Comment: You are both *reading* and *assigning to* `a` with `a +=`. That makes `a` a *local* variable, but you can't read it until it has been assigned. In `f11()` you are assigning to a *slice*, which means `a` itself is not bound to, and that leaves it as a closure.

Comment: @MartijnPieters then how does accessing with the indices work ?

Comment: Accessing with the indices won't alter what `a` is pointing to. It'll ask `a` to alter what the indices point to, `a` *itself* the same, a reference to an array object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, you used *augmented assignment*:

```
a += v
```

That makes `a` a *local variable*; all binding actions, including assignment, makes a variable local. This is determined at compile time. See the [*Naming and binding* section](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding) of the Python execution model:

> If a name is bound in a block, it is a local variable of that block.
>
> *[...]*
>
> The following constructs bind names: *[...]* targets that are identifiers if occurring in an assignment, *[...]*.

`a` is a target that is an identifier.

Because `a` is considered a local, attempting to *read* the reference before it has been bound, will throw a `UnboundLocal` exception. The augmented assignment has to read `a` before it can assign back to `a`, hence the exception.

Your second example does not bind to `a` anywhere in `f2`; assigning to a *slice* of `a` won't alter the name `a` itself. You assigned to `a[0,:]`; that's not an identifier, that's a slice.

You can make the first example work by replacing `a += v` with `np.add(a, v, out=a)`.

Comment: Not `a.extend(v)`, because `a` is a NumPy array, not a list. `np.add(a, v, out=a)` should work.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  There is one more thing I don't understand. Please see the edited question.
On printing the `locals()` f11 has a in locals whereas f1 doesn't

Comment: @vin: `locals()` includes closures. In `f1() -> f2()`, `a` has *not yet been bound*, so won't show up in `locals()`. In `f11() -> f2()`, `a` is a closure and is visible in `locals()`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters does python have a two pass compilation ?  I assumed that python was interpreted language and locals() in both `f1` and `f11` should be the same as `a` is not accessed as yet

Comment: @MartijnPieters are closures are decided at runtime or compile-time? So while adding f1::f2 the interpreter found that a local copy of `a` is accessed and hence removed `a` from locals() ?

Comment: @vin: closures are determined at compile time; that's because you need to set up the closure in the parent scope and pass it to the function object created for `f2` so it can resolve the closure. `locals()` can only show *already bound names*; that's what binding does, it adds a name to the namespace and not having bound `a` yet in the local namespace of `f2()` means it is not yet present in `locals()`.